# jQuery: .closest adds the class attribute, but not my intended value

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, closest

Quick preview of the problem: using `.closest()`, I'm able to stick a class attribute on all instances of the target element, but it won't insert the class value on any that have an extra `<div>` in the ancestor DOM.

First, here's the jQuery:

```
// Throw class="errorWrap" on any <li> element that contains a field that doesn't validate
highlight: function(element) {
    $(element).closest("li").addClass("errorWrap");
}
```

*(…The 'highlight:' is part of the Validate plug-in…)*

And here's a snippet of my HTML:

```
<li>
    <div>
        <span class="reqField">*</span> Have you been employed with us before?<br />
        <label class="radioInput"><input type="radio" name="app_prior_employ" value="Yes" /> Yes</label>
        <label class="radioInput"><input type="radio" name="app_prior_employ" value="No" /> No</label>
    </div>

    <div>
        <label for="app_prior_employ_date">If <em>yes</em>, when were you employed?</label><br />
        <input type="text" name="app_prior_employ_date" value="" size="40" id="app_prior_employ_date" />
    </div>
</li>
```

…now, with the above, the class attribute **will** be added to the opening `<li>` tag when it's supposed to, but it's value will be **empty** rather than *errorWrap*

As I mentioned at the top of this question, this issue occurs on only instances that have the `<div>` elements in the mix (as they do immediately above). This issue *does not* occur on other instances where the `<div>` is not in place, such as:

```
<li>
    <span class="reqField">*</span> Can you travel if a job requires it?<br />
    <label class="radioInput"><input type="radio" name="app_travel_for_job" value="Yes" /> Yes</label>
    <label class="radioInput"><input type="radio" name="app_travel_for_job" value="No" /> No</label>
</li>
```

I can't figure out why jQuery would succeed in adding the class attribute everywhere I want it to, but fail to insert the value I've defined only in those that have an extra element in the DOM. Am I using `.closest()` improperly?

**Added moments later:** Here's a marked-up screen shot of the issue: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aiiaX.png

Comment: It should be fine. Please create a http://jsfiddle.net example that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: What if you do that with `.parents('li')` ?

Comment: Same exact result, oddly enough, if I use .parents('li').

Comment: It works fine in this test fiddle, so there must be something else in your app that is causing the headache: http://jsfiddle.net/rgvwP/1/

Comment: jlbruno: you're awesome. It looks like it's an issue for me to iron-out elsewhere in the code. http://img219.imageshack.us/img219/8788/fuuuuuu.jpg

Comment: If you can create a fiddle with enough of your code that DOES replicate the problem, it'll be easier for us to help debug...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using closest() properly, but maybe the context in which the highlight() function is wrong in that instance. In the scripts inspector, put a breakpoint inside the highlight function, and see if element is actually the input you think it is.

Alternatively, you say the li has a class, but no value when the div is in the mix. Maybe the class is getting set then immediately unset. Using the script inspector and setting breakpoints will help you figure that out.

Comment: the Validate plugin returns the element as the first argument. So it should be working with `parents('li')`

Comment: I'll definitely need to educate myself a bit on all things breakpoint/firebug/etc. I can inspect the HTML/CSS like a wizard, but I don't know what I'm doing in the Script area(s).

Comment: I just confirmed that the issue is DEFINITELY your second suggestion: the class value is being set properly but it's also being immediately unset. It appears as though *unhighlight* (which strips the class and should only run when the field validates) is running right away.

Answer (score 0):

Use parents instead

```
$(element).parents("li").addClass("errorWrap");
```

Comment: Same exact result, oddly enough, if I use .parents('li'). ( Also, I added a screen shot to help, if needed: http://i.imgur.com/aiiaX.png )